# std::set_intersection for array and list

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to ask question regarding std::set_intersection. I have used it for lists and is working well if I am using

```
std::set_intersection(list1.begin(),list1.end(),list2.begin(),list2.end(), std::back_inserter(Get_intersect));
```

*But I have never used it with arrays. what about if I'll take array here? I have taken array in argument and want to perform intersection.*

```
std::set_intersection(a[].begin(),a[].end(),list2.begin(),list2.end(), std::back_inserter(Get_intersect));
```

Getting this error: `syntax error : ']'`. If I'll remove this `[]` from `a[]` then I am unable to begin and end my array.

Comment: Clearly this has nothing to do with `set_intersection`. You just need to find out how to get begin and end iterators from an array.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah I know there is not any issue with set_intersection because same function is working well with lists as I have mentioned. Only the issue is with array.

Comment: So why is your title and question focused on `set_intersection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `std::begin` and `std::end`.

```
std::set_intersection(
    std::begin(a), std::end(a),
    list2.begin(), list2.end(),
    std::back_inserter(Get_intersect)
);
```

Note that since `a` is not a set, you need to take care yourself that it is sorted (which is a prerequisite for `std::set_intersection` to work, see the [set_intersection documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Full example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // for std::begin and std::end
#include <set>
#include <vector>

void printVector(std::vector<int> vec)
{
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> list2;
    list2.push_back(2);
    list2.push_back(4);
    std::vector<int> intersection;
    std::set_intersection(
        std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        list2.begin(), list2.end(),
        std::back_inserter(intersection)
    );
    printVector(intersection);
}
```

Comment: thank you s much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual array (and not a pointer) then you can use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to get "iterators" for the array.

What those basically does is giving you *pointers* to the beginning and the end (plus one). And you can actually pass pointers yourself, if you have the size:

```
int* pointer_to_array = ...;
size_t num_elements = ...;

some_function_taking_iterators(
    pointer_to_array,    // This is the begin "iterator"
    pointer_to_array + num_elements  // This is the end "iterator"
);
```

Comment: @jaochim Thank you so much :)